# CodeIgniter where and like sql query statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am trying to do this sql query on codeigniter

```
SELECT* FROM person WHERE type = 'staff' AND description LIKE 'university%'
```

I am not sure if it is correct...

```
$this->db->get_where('person' , array('type'=>'staff'))
         ->like('description','university%')
         ->result_array();
```

does anyone have an idea about my case? thanks in advance ...

Comment: For query debugging please consider using CI profiler, you will always know what query you are running `$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [*Active Record*](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) you can do so

```
$query = $this->db->select('*')
             ->from('person')
             ->where('type','staff')
             ->like('description','university','after')
             ->get();

$result = $query->result_array();
```

Make sure you pass `after` as a third parameter in `like()` function so active record will add the wild card i.e `%` after `university` so it will look like `LIKE 'university%'`

Answer (score 0):

I never used chaining(even though i know it's possible), but breaking down your question should be easy ;

```
$this->db->from('person');
$this->db->where('type','staff');
$this->db->where('description', 'university%');
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result_array();
return $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) has this explained very well, but their API is very simple. To produce the query you need the relevant code which looks like this:

```
$this->db->select('*')
     ->from('person');
     ->where('type', 'staff')
     ->like('description','university');

$query  = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result_array();
```